# Django Celery reduce time, 5 hours to complete 1000 tasks

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm running on a development environment so this maybe different in production, but when I run a task from Django Celery, it seems to only fetch tasks from the broker every 10-20 seconds. I'm only testing at this point but lets say I'm sending around 1000 tasks this means it will take over 5 hours+ to complete.

Is this is normal? Should it be quicker? Or I'm I doing something wrong?

**This is my task**

```
class SendMessage(Task):
    name = "Sending SMS"
    max_retries = 10
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_id, gateway_id=None, **kwargs):
        logging.debug("About to send a message.")

        # Because we don't always have control over transactions
        # in our calling code, we will retry up to 10 times, every 3
        # seconds, in order to try to allow for the commit to the database
        # to finish. That gives the server 30 seconds to write all of
        # the data to the database, and finish the view.
        try:
            message = Message.objects.get(pk=message_id)
        except Exception as exc:
            raise SendMessage.retry(exc=exc)

        if not gateway_id:
            if hasattr(message.billee, 'sms_gateway'):
                gateway = message.billee.sms_gateway
            else:
                gateway = Gateway.objects.all()[0]
        else:
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=gateway_id)

        #response = gateway._send(message)
        print(message_id)

        logging.debug("Done sending message.")
```

**which gets run from my view**

```
 for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=request.user etc etc):
            SendMessage.delay(e.id, message)
```

Comment: What Broker are you using to send tasks? How long does it take to execute a single task without celery?

Comment: What is your backend?  What logging handler are you using?  How are you launching celery?

Comment: @JeffS I'm using Amazon SQS.

Comment: @Rob I'm running Celery via terminal using command 'python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info' as this is just me testing.

Comment: @Spike I'd be curious to know how long SendMessage.run() takes from the django shell

Comment: In the dev environment you are, probably, running a single worker and handling tasks sequentially.  You have two remote systems with retry (backend and sms message gateway) so it's not hard to imagine a minimum of a few seconds per try on success.  Is message sending succeeding?  If it's not there's your 10-20 seconds ... the retry mixed with network latency and SMS message timeout.

Comment: @Rob the message is succeeding, I'm watching the output, it does say 'succeeded in 0.460468053818s: None' but it then seems to wait around 10 before showing Got task from broker: sms.tasks.SendMessage etc

Comment: @Rob, so are you saying that in production this will be different? What do you mean by 'running a single worker', how is this different in production. I will be running on a EC2 machine Celery and SQS as my broker when in production.

Comment: This is actually a known issue with the Celery SQS transport for the moment: https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/202  The problem was introduced with the support for long polling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is normal. This is the default workers to be used. They set this default so that it will not affect the performance of the app.

There is another way to change it. The task decorator can take a number of options that change the way the task behaves. Any keyword argument passed to the task decorator will actually be set as an attribute of the resulting task class.

You can set the rate limit which limits the number of tasks that can be run in a given time frame.

```
//means hundred tasks a minute, another /s (second) and /h (hour)
CELERY_DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT = "100/m" --> set in settings
```

Comment: thanks Catherine, So what is the actual default set to out of the box?  what would you recommend  as a good rate limit, lets say on a small EC2 instance?

Comment: 1,000 messages per 24 hour period at a maximum rate of one message per second. When you set the rate limit, set also  `CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False`